# How do I replace bytes in multiple files in one directory recursively with Python 3.5.1?

Tags: python, recursion, replace, byte

I'm looking to achieve the following with multiple files in the same directory from one run of a script:

```
fh = open("*.bin", "r+b")  
fh.seek(0)  
fh.write(bytes([0x4F, 0x67]))  
fh.close()
```

My end goal is to have, say, myByteReplacement.py that, when ran (from within the same directory as the files, or otherwise if need be), opens all files in the directory with a .bin extension, then replaces the first two bytes in each file with the same 2 bytes that I specify.

From what I've gathered (at least with Windows), an asterisk as a wildcard doesn't work. I can't seem to nail this down despite trying various solutions related to os.walk, glob, and others I've seen mentioned here on the site and research via the Google machine.

Thank you for any solutions or points of research you might offer!

**EDIT:** *Thanks to the information from responses so far, I've built out what I was ultimately looking to achieve. Here's the final result, for those who might stumble upon this later.*

```
# This script looks for files of a specific filetype (.bin) in a specified
# directory (C:/Convert). It then replaces the first two bytes of those
# files with 2 bytes that I specify (0x4F, 0x67). Finally, it renames those
# files to what their actual extension should be (.m32).

import os, re

path = "C:/Convert"
os.chdir( path )
files = os.listdir( path )

for filename in files:
if re.match('.*\.bin', filename):
fh = open(filename, "r+b")
fh.seek(0)
fh.write(bytes([0x4F, 0x67]))
fh.close()
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
os.rename(filename, name + ".m32")
```

Comment: `open("*.bin", "r+b") ` opens a single file named `*.bin`.  You need to read this directory, and iterator over the fioenames, and only opening the ones that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do

```
os.listdir("your directory")
```

which will give you a list of files.  Then do your code on each file

Comment: Thank you for this; it's exactly what I needed to finish fleshing it out. This ended up being my final solution (if anyone has an idea to make this more optimal somehow, I dig optimization):  

    import os

    path = "C:/filepathhere"
    files = os.listdir( path )

    for file in files:
    fh = open(file, "r+b")
    fh.seek(0)
    fh.write(bytes([0x4F, 0x67]))
    fh.close()

Comment: ASMStephen: If the files aren't in the current directory, you'll need use `open(os.path.join(directory_name, file_name))` for each file name after getting a list of them from `listdir(directory_name)`.

Comment: wanna check the answer? if it helped?

Comment: Thanks, @martineau. That helped me figure out a similar solution. Here is the result of what I was looking to achieve (search a directory for files that match a specific file type, replace specific bytes in them, then rename them to what their real extensions are) is as follows: import os, re
path = "C:/Convert"
os.chdir( path )
files = os.listdir( path )
for filename in files:
if re.match('.*\.bin', filename):
fh = open(filename, "r+b")
fh.seek(0)
fh.write(bytes([0x4F, 0x67]))
fh.close()
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
os.rename(filename, name + ".m32")

Comment: ASMStephen: To do that sort of thing, I suggest you instead use `glob.glob('C:/Convert/*.bin')` which will return a list of complete pathnames to each file in the directory that match the given pattern. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob). Note the other `os.path` functions like `splitext()` will work fine with full pathnames — which should simplify your code somewhat.